# transform.LookAt() causes Y angle to increase by 180

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I am trying to create a third person spaceship movement.

The spaceship rotates about all axes at its position, and has a throttle control to move in forward direction. There is a camera which is always behind it. I am not making the camera a child because I want the camera to NOT follow the rotation about z axes.

The camera has a script, which keeps its position a fixed distance behind the spaceship, and then calls `transform.LookAt(spaceShipTarget)`.

The problem is that as I rotate the ship around global x axes 90 degrees, the y axis of camera suddenly does a 180 degree rotation. The camera control script is below:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Utility
{
    public class FollowBehind : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform target;
        public float distance;
        public float delay;

        private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

        private void LateUpdate()
        {
            Vector3 offset = target.transform.TransformVector(0, 0, distance);
            Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;
            Vector3 finalPosition = target.position + offset;
            transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(currentPosition,
                finalPosition, ref velocity, delay);
            transform.LookAt(target);
        }
    }
}
```

Why would that happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: so you rotate ship on x by 90 and the camera makes a 180 jump on y?

Comment: Is there any other code modifying your camera transform? If so, could you include that as well in a code snippet? At present, the given information doesn't seem like enough to narrow down the problem...

Comment: @Serlite done...thanks!

Comment: @NikaKasradze yes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have with the rotation of the camera is probably caused by the script you use to make the camera follow the spaceship, probably because when you rotate the spaceship the rotation (and probably the position) of the camera are affected.

What you could do instead is make both the spaceship and camera child of another object, and then add a script to this parent object. Now you can put some code in the script of the parent to move the parent itself (this way both camera and spaceship will move together, and you don't need to keep them together manually) and also in the script of the parent you can put some code to rotate the spaceship and camera individually or together based on specific inputs.